# Bootstrap 4 container full screen width without container-fluid class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want to give the container a 100% width using media queries, having the elements contained in a larger screen and not contained in a small one or vice versa. This code is just an example and it works with Bootstrap v4 alpha 6, but in the last release it doesn't work anymore.

Anybody knows a solution?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujbpxzfo/3/)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you dose not remove  `container` class? Without it you have `width=100%`

Comment: You should only be utilizing `container` in combination with Navbar if you want to constrain its width.  Are you trying to make it fixed-width at larger resolutions or is it 100% all the time?

Comment: What's the reason you want to have 100% width but don't want to use the `container-fluid` class? (maybe there are better solutions than what you are trying)

Comment: OK, It seems you want to have the effects of `container` class when the width is `larger than 500px` else you want `width=100%`. I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509655/bootstrap-4-container-full-screen-width-without-container-fluid-class/#48510181) here for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It fit the `navbar` to the width of the page when the page width is **less than `500px`**, else it has the normal effects of a `container` class on your element. If you want change the page size and test it you can use **[jsFiddel demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ovj06rgf/2/)**.

[image]

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
      padding-right:0 !important;
      padding-left:0 !important;
      max-width: initial !important;
  }
}
body{
  background:#a7b7bf !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And if you want always the `navbar` fill full width of the page you can easily remove `container` class from wrapper div:

```css
body{
  background:#a7b7bf !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the container to fulfill 100% of screen width with any given media width, 500px was an example, i changed it to be more clear.

Comment: @GabrielSouza, OK I changed my answer and added `max-width: initial !important;` to it to support larger width than `500px`, such as `1000px` too. Also I updated the _jeFiddle demo_. Click on it in the answer to see a live demo in jsFiddle and change the page size there. Last note: you forget to put a _dot_ before `container` selector in the CSS styles in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it correctly without using the `container-fluid` class but instead putting everything inside into a `container` (click the "run code snippet" button and expand to full screen to see that it's indeed full width):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                       Dropdown
                   </a>
                   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
           <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
               <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Seems `navbar ` not 100%?

Comment: It is 100%. Expand to full screen to see.

Comment: No, it is not. The background bar is 100%, but not the navbar, text with links, left margin and right margin are obvious.

Comment: The author does not want to use `container-fluid`, but wants to have the effects, You can just change your `container` to  `container-fluid` to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @ildflue Aha, that's what you meant. Yes, that's the nature of the `.container` as opposed to `.container-fluid`.  `.container-fluid` is NOT recommended because it's a nightmare for users on wide 4K screens.

Comment: that's why the author wants to have a different solution than that.